# Sum of Gaussian densities

Tags: real-analysis, normal-distribution, gaussian-integral

I wanted to know if one could write the sum of Gaussian densities with different deviations as a Gaussian density. More specifically,

For $\sigma>0$, let $f_\sigma$ be defined as :$$f_\sigma(x) \triangleq e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}.$$

Let $\sigma_1,\sigma_2>0$, does it exist a $\sigma>0$ and a coefficient $\alpha>0$ such that:
$$\alpha f_{\sigma} = f_{\sigma_1}+f_{\sigma_2}.$$

Any hint, ideas or solutions will be highly appreciated! Thank you very much.

Comment: Gaussian densities have a $-$ in the exponent, so for example for $N(0,\sigma^2)$ you have a density of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{x^2}{\sigma^2}}$

Comment: Thank you Henry for Noticing me the error, I was obviously refering to this density.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible unless $\sigma_{1}=\sigma_{2}$ (in which case you can take $\sigma=\sigma_{1}$ and $\alpha=2$).

To see this, proceed assuming $\sigma_{1}\neq\sigma_{2}$.
Suppose we can find $\sigma$ and $\alpha$ such that
$$
\alpha f_{\sigma}(x)=f_{\sigma_{1}}(x)+f_{\sigma_{2}}(x)
$$
for all $x$.
Substitute $x=0,1,\sqrt{2}$ to get three equations:
\begin{align*}
\alpha & =1+1\\
\alpha e^{1/(2\sigma^{2})} & =e^{1/(2\sigma_{1}^{2})}+e^{1/(2\sigma_{2}^{2})}\\
\alpha e^{1/\sigma^{2}} & =e^{1/\sigma_{1}^{2}}+e^{1/\sigma_{2}^{2}}
\end{align*}
From the first two equations it follows that $\alpha=2$ and
$$
\sigma^{2}=\left[2\ln\left(\frac{e^{1/(2\sigma_{1}^{2})}+e^{1/(2\sigma_{2}^{2})}}{2}\right)\right]^{-1}.
$$
Substituting these quantities into the third equation,
$$
\left(\frac{e^{1/(2\sigma_{1}^{2})}+e^{1/(2\sigma_{2}^{2})}}{2}\right)^{2}=\frac{e^{1/\sigma_{1}^{2}}+e^{1/\sigma_{2}^{2}}}{2}.
$$
Defining $u=e^{1/(2\sigma_{1}^{2})}$ and $v=e^{1/(2\sigma_{2}^{2})}$, we can rewrite the above as
$$
\left(u - v\right)^2 = 0,
$$
a contradiction since $u \neq v$.

Comment: Thank you @parsiad for you detail answer but I can't see how you get the three equations from the definition. Could you explain me a bit more this step please ?

Comment: @Gaetano: Substitute $x=0$ into the equation $\alpha f_\sigma(x) = f_{\sigma_1}(x) + f_{\sigma_2}(x)$ to get one equation, substitute $x=1$ to get another, etc.

Comment: But I don't have a $1/\sigma$ before the exponential in the definition. I don't understand how do get these $\sigma$. It is not a normalized Gaussian

Comment: @Gaetano: My mistake; I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much but how do you have the contradiction ?

Comment: @Gaetano: The left hand side and right hand side of the last equation are not equal

Comment: Thank you ! @parsiad

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to answer this informally simply by considering a graph such as the green one (which is the sum of the other two).  Do you think it can be described as a *SINGLE* gaussian??  Look at its shape!

[image]